# pandas how to filter and slice with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, filtering, slice

Using pandas, how do I return dataframe filtered by value of 2 in 'GEN' column, value 20 in 'AGE' column and exclude columns with name 'GEN' and 'BP'? Thanks in advance:)

```
AGE GEN BMI     BP  S1  S2      S3  S4  S5      S6  Y
59  2   32.1    101 157 93.2    38  4   4.8598  87  151
48  1   21.6    87  183 103.2   70  3   3.8918  69  75
72  2   30.5    93  156 93.6    41  4   4.6728  85  141
24  1   25.3    84  198 131.4   40  5   4.8903  89  206
50  1   23      101 192 125.4   52  4   4.2905  80  135
23  1   22.6    89  139 64.8    61  2   4.1897  68  97
20  2   22      90  160 99.6    50  3   3.9512  82  138
66  2   26.2    114 255 185     56  4.5 4.2485  92  63
60  2   32.1    83  179 119.4   42  4   4.4773  94  110
20  1   30      85  180 93.4    43  4   5.3845  88  310
```

Comment: might be a bit of an overkill -> this selects via the index : ``df.set_index(['AGE', 'GEN']).loc[[(20, 2)], lambda df: df.columns.difference(['GEN', 'BP'])]``

Answer (score 1):

You can do this -

```
cols = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['GEN','BP'])]

out=df.loc[(df['GEN'] == 2) & (df['AGE'] == 20),cols]
```

**OR**

```
out=df.query("'GEN'==2 and 'AGE'==20").loc[cols]
```